# How to load the video at a specific time?

Tags: javascript, html

Edit: I have reviewed the other posts with a similar question and those do not resolve this issue. The #-t open just gets passed as a GET variable to my proxy script.

The following is to load a video.  The source of the video is a php script that checks to ensure user is logged in then outputs the video. This is to ensure that only people logged in can download the video.
How do I specify  a time to start the video position at?

```html
<video id="test" width="640" height="360" controlsList="nodownload" controls>
  <source src="vidRedir.php?v=video" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Append `#t=<time in seconds>` to the URL. For example, setting `src` to `vidRedir.php?v=video#t=30` will start the video at 30 seconds.

See [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery#specifying_playback_range).

Comment: Ive tried this and it does not work because it passes it to the php script as a GET variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
const video = document.querySelector('video');
video.currentTime = <Your time here>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime